# Typo3: How to create typolinks in a scheduler/cron script

Tags: scheduler, typo3, realurl

I need to create links to the frontend website inside a scheduler task. I've searched and looked around and what I have found is an example script that initiates the TSFE. After that I can initiate tslib_cObj to create some links; I thought.

But what I get is a recursion error as soon as I try to create a typolink using $cObj->typoLink_URL(1); fe. or any other method that allows creating a typolink.

The following is the script I use to initiate the TSFE inside $GLOBALS, just like when working inside an extension in the frontend:

```
<?php
function initTSFE($pageUid = 1, $overrule = FALSE) {
    // declare
    $temp_TSFEclassName = t3lib_div::makeInstanceClassName('tslib_fe');

    // begin
    if (!is_object($GLOBALS['TT']) || $overrule === TRUE) {
        $GLOBALS['TT'] = new t3lib_timeTrack;
        $GLOBALS['TT']->start();
    }

    if ((!is_object($GLOBALS['TSFE']) || $overrule === TRUE) && is_int($pageUid)) {
        // builds TSFE object
        $GLOBALS['TSFE'] = new $temp_TSFEclassName($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'],
            $pageUid, $type=0, $no_cache=0, $cHash='', $jumpurl='', $MP='', $RDCT='');

        // builds rootline
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_pageSelect');
        $rootLine = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->getRootLine($pageUid);

            // init template
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_tsparser_ext');
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->tt_track = 0;// Do not log time-performance information
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->init();

        // this generates the constants/config + hierarchy info for the template.
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->runThroughTemplates($rootLine, $start_template_uid=0);
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->generateConfig();
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->loaded=1;

        // get config array and other init from pagegen
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getConfigArray();
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->linkVars = ''.$GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['config']['linkVars'];

        if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['config']['simulateStaticDocuments_pEnc_onlyP']) {
            foreach (t3lib_div::trimExplode(',',$GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['config']['simulateStaticDocuments_pEnc_onlyP'],1) as $temp_p) {
                $GLOBALS['TSFE']->pEncAllowedParamNames[$temp_p]=1;
            }
        }

        // builds a cObj
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->newCObj();
    }
}
```

What I am trying todo in the scheduler task is the following:

```
<?php
public function execute() {
    $this->initTSFE();
    $cObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
    var_dump($cObj->getTypoLink_URL(1));exit;
}
```

This is showing me the following result upon executing this task via the scheduler:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbB35.png

Any help is very much appreciated =)

NOTE: The 1 value inside getTypoLink_URL does exist as a page in Typo3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with this initTSFE() method I was trying to use. I am not quit sure what, but I've found a different version of it that does seem to work:

```
public function initTSFE($pageUid=1) {
    require_once(PATH_tslib.'class.tslib_fe.php');
    require_once(PATH_t3lib.'class.t3lib_userauth.php');
    require_once(PATH_tslib.'class.tslib_feuserauth.php');
    require_once(PATH_t3lib.'class.t3lib_cs.php');
    require_once(PATH_tslib.'class.tslib_content.php');
    require_once(PATH_t3lib.'class.t3lib_tstemplate.php');
    require_once(PATH_t3lib.'class.t3lib_page.php');

    $TSFEclassName = t3lib_div::makeInstanceClassName('tslib_fe');

    if (!is_object($GLOBALS['TT'])) {
        $GLOBALS['TT'] = new t3lib_timeTrack;
        $GLOBALS['TT']->start();
    }

    // Create the TSFE class.
    $GLOBALS['TSFE'] = new $TSFEclassName($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'],$pageUid,'0',1,'','','','');
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->connectToMySQL();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->initFEuser();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fetch_the_id();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getPageAndRootline();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->initTemplate();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->getFileName_backPath = PATH_site;
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->forceTemplateParsing = 1;
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getConfigArray();
}
```

[Thank you voancea!](http://www.typo3.net/forum/beitraege//39975/#pid377987)